# Azure RM Template. Pass complex value to 3rd level nested template

Tags: azure

I have a parent template with 2 levels of nested templates, azuredeploy.json->vmReferenceTemplate.json->datadiskreference.json When I'm passing the required value from 2nd level to 3rd it deploys fine, but it doesn't work when passing the exact same value from 1st level to 3rd level nested template. I would like to numDataDisks value from azuredeploy.json to datadiskreference.json I have a very complex template and in order for it to work I must pass the value from 1st level. Here is striped down version that works.
azuredeploy.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "parameters": {
    ,,,
    "numberOfVMs": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 8,
    },
    "numberOfDataDisks": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        2,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex(1),'-','reference')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "copy": {
        "name": "vmReferenceTemplateLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfVMs')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('vmReferenceTemplateTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('vmReferenceTemplateTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "numDataDisks": {
            "value": "[parameters('numberOfVMs')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
...
```

vmReferenceTemplate.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "parameters": {
    ...
    "numberOfVMs": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 2
    },
    "numberOfDataDisks": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        2,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  "resources": 
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('dataDisksReferenceTemplateName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "copy": {
        "name": "dataDiskReferenceLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('copyNestedReference')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('dataDiskReferenceTemplateUri')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "vmName": {
            "value": "[parameters('dataDisksVMnameReference')]"
          },
          "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "[variables('var_storageAccountName')]"
          },
          "numDataDisks": {
            "value": "[parameters('numberOfDataDisks')[copyIndex()]]"
          },
          "sizeOfEachDataDiskInGB": {
            "value": "[variables('sizeOfEachDataDiskInGB')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
```

And this is how I'm trying to pass values from 1st level to 3rd level, but it fails with the error `"Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'numDataDisks' at line '36' and column '22' is not valid.'."`
azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "parameters": {
    ,,,
    "numberOfVMs": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 8,
    },
    "numberOfDataDisks": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        2,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex(1),'-','reference')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "copy": {
        "name": "vmReferenceTemplateLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfVMs')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('vmReferenceTemplateTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('vmReferenceTemplateTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "numDataDisks": {
            "value": "[parameters('numberOfDataDisks')[copyIndex()]]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
...
```

vmReferenceTemplate.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "parameters": {
    ,,,
    "numberOfVMs": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 2,
    },
    "numberOfDataDisks": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        2,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('dataDisksReferenceTemplateName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "copy": {
        "name": "dataDiskReferenceLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('copyNestedReference')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('dataDiskReferenceTemplateUri')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "vmName": {
            "value": "[parameters('dataDisksVMnameReference')]"
          },
          "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "[variables('var_storageAccountName')]"
          },
          "numDataDisks": {
            "value": "[parameters('numDataDisks')]"
          },
          "sizeOfEachDataDiskInGB": {
            "value": "[variables('sizeOfEachDataDiskInGB')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
...
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are passing the value 1 > 2 > 3 and it doesn't propagate properly from the parent to the child of the child? also, MS advises to use 2 levels of templates ;) so have you considered 1 > 3, output of 3 to 2? so that the template has only 2 levels?

Comment: Yes 1 > 2 > 3 is not passing. I'm afraid 2 levels is not an option for me as I'm passing keyvaults to copy VM (can only be done with nested template in case of copy VMs) and passing variable amount of data disks to that copy VMs (can only be done with nested template in case of copy VMs too).

Comment: I don't have time now, but I will come back to this tomorrow and show you what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go, folks, just like I said in the comments, lets do a magic trick! Lets create a template with 2 nested templates, but pass output of 1 nested template to the other one!

```
"resources": [
    {
        ...
        "dependsOn": [
            "datadiskcopy" << DEPENDS ON ANOTHER TEMPLATE COPY LOOP !!!
        ],
        ...
            "parameters": {
                "adminPassword": {
                    "reference": {
                        "keyVault": {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxx"
                        },
                        "secretName": "[concat('secret', copyindex(1))]"
                    } << KEYVAULT REFERENCE YOU NEED !!
                },
                "diskObject": {
                    "value": "[reference(concat('nested-datadisk-', copyIndex())).outputs.result.value]" << REFERENCE ANOTHER NESTED DEPLOYMENT OUTPUT !!
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "name": "[concat('nested-datadisk-', copyIndex())]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "copy": {
            "name": "datadiskcopy",
            "count": "[parameters('LoopCount')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/4c74356b41/armotron/master/ml-vm-ml-dd-kv-nst-dd",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "numDataDisks": {
                    "value": "[parameters('numberOfDataDisksPerVM')[copyIndex()]]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I will update links shortly, as I decided to rename my templates a bit, but you can take a look at [armotron repo](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron) on my github for samples already.

This is using managed disks for simplicity, but you can use unmanaged ( going to be hardcore, thou )

PS. You might again run into caching issue, copy the data not from the `RAW` link. just tested this thing, works for me, you can extend it further.

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I just realized that I wasn't passing values from lvl1->lvl2->lvl3 but rather lvl2->lvl1->lvl2->lvl3 which is impossible, unless I screwed up somewhere in the code along the way. This message does answer my question. Thanks, @4c74356b41!

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer your question directly, it might cast some light on better solutions. We went several rounds with ARM-templates for provisioning our Azure infrastructure, including nested templates as you're doing now. We ended up ditching nested templates for the following reasons:

1. They ended up providing little value in terms of reuse. Each time we wanted to reuse a shared template, it almost always needed some adjustments to the specific scenario in question. That meant bump the version number, make adjustments and make the new version available on public Internet while also having the old versions available.
2. The lack of constructs for conditionals (yes you can hack them in, but it makes the template unclear) made it even more difficult to achieve reusable templates.

Our ARM-templates are currently like this: Each Resource Group has its own git-repository in our Github account, and each resource in the resource group has its own template. A repository for a resource group looks for instance like this:

```
my_group
├── cloud-config.yaml
├── deploy.ps1
├── deploy.sh
└── resources
    ├── load_balancer.json
    ├── nsg.json
    ├── storage_account.json
    └── virtual_machine.json
```

Having separate templates for each resource makes maintenance much easier. The `deploy.sh` file is at the moment just  a series of `az group deployment create`-commands that deploys all the files, the same with the powershell script. We no longer need to have our ARM-templates on public Internet without authentication. You'll also notice that since this ARM-template is only meant for one reason group, we no longer need parameter files, parameters are handled along with the rest of the code.

I believe this setup provides much more flexibility than one giant ARM-template depending on nested templates. We can manage everything we want in isolation (like `cloud-config.yaml`) and later use scripts to generate ARM-templates for deployment. We are currently experimenting with creating a git-tag for every deployment and then use git to figure out which files have changed since last deployment.

Comment: his case is somewhat different, he needs those because of "random" amount of disks for vm and because of keyvault. but I'm also a bit upset with ARM templates, they are somewhat lacking

Comment: True, just saying that if the starting point is "a very complex template" (as ARM-templates tends to turn out), and he needs concepts to handle conditionals or other logic-based operators, I'd create as simple as possible ARM-template and leave the rest of the job for more suited scripting languages.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Your set up does look incredibly efficient. However, I must use nested templates as it's the only way to implement variables amount of disks for multiple VMs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#create-multiple-instances-when-copy-wont-work and I also must use nested templates for referencing secrets from key vault as password for those VMs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-a-secret-with-dynamic-id